# Calling Wp 8.1 Silverlight phone app in Wp 8.1 WinRT Phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, zxing, qr-code

Is it is possible to initiate a wp 8.1 Silverlight phone from wp8.1 WinRT phone app?

As i were trying for build a app for Scanning functionality,upto my knowledge there is no inbuilt options to scan the bar qode are QR code. When i search it for some resources, i found and many suggesting to use Zxing libraries. Though i tried with that and the success rate of the Scan was not that much satisfied.

When look through the Silverlight wp app, it was working quite well. So i was planning to create a seperate a app for this in wp 8.1 Silverlight app and that to be initiated from the WinRT phone app.

Please suggest some ideas on this.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly. There is no way for a Windows Phone app to directly launch a specific other app. Apps can launch only files or URIs into their default handlers.

You can hack this by defining a protocol for your app and launching that, but you cannot guarantee that your SL app is installed. The protocol launch is fire and forget and cannot return data. The SL app could save it's data to a custom data type handled by the runtime app and launch that file, but this will all be pretty cumbersome and likely obvious to the user.

I'd try to keep all of the functionality in one app, whether that be a runtime app or a Silverlight app.